# Swift Alamofire - POST request using parameters of NULL value

Tags: ios, swift, post, alamofire, option-type

I have the Alamofire POST request in the following and the value of my parameter is optional. I would like to allow users to call this API to set the required parameter, even though it is NULL (it's kind of reset to empty default value).

Here's my request and the parameter `status` is an optional variable that it's expected to be accepting null value:

```swift
let URL_UPDATE_STATUS = URL_HOME + "/v1/updateStatus/" + dataId
let parameters: [String : Any] = ["status": status as Any]
                
Alamofire.request(URL_UPDATE_STATUS, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: self.headers).responseString { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print("[Log] Update Status Success")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("[ERROR] UpdateStatus - \(error)")
                
        APIErrorHandler(response: response, error: error)
    }
}
```

However, I tried several times and it always returns some errors. I tried to be optional and I found that it isn't interpolated (i.e. it becomes `"Optional(\"SOME_STATUS\")"`). When I tried to force unwrap the string, those null values will cause fatal error. And also, I tried the methods of passing null as the value of the request parameter but it doesn't work anyway.

I don't understand how I should fix it, and could anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: in case Optional  value is nil then you are force casting nil value to Any which make it crashes.
`let parameters: [String : Any] = ["status": status as Any]`

Comment: Thanks @Same7Farouk! I tried to force casting ``nil`` because it will make the parameter value look like ``"Optional(\"SOME_STATUS\")"``...

Answer (score 1):

You can create the parameters dictionary then assign values to it.
In this case they key would either have a value of not exist.

```swift
var parameters: [String : Any] = [:]
parameters["status"] = status
```

Comment: Thanks zombie! But I intend to set the parameter with ``nil`` value (i.e. something like ``status=NULL`` as the query string for the POST request), to somehow reset the status flag.

Comment: @markandshare nil means that the parameter key does not exist which is the same as not sending it. Or do you mean `NSNull()`

Comment: I tried passing NSNull() before but the status will be set as a string like ``"<null>"``... Am I using wrong encoding method and how does the result look like that?

Comment: @zombie Thanks, I tried to pass nil as a parameter in a request's body and the  `NSNull()` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass null parameter you can check it has value the pass it

check this code

```
let URL_UPDATE_STATUS = URL_HOME + "/v1/updateStatus/" + dataId
var parameters: [String : Any]? = nil
if let status = status {
    parameters  = ["status": status]
}
Alamofire.request(URL_UPDATE_STATUS, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: self.headers).responseString { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("[Log] Update Status Success")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("[ERROR] UpdateStatus - \(error)")
                
        APIErrorHandler(response: response, error: error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Same7Farouk! I'm not setting the parameter ``nil`` but I need to set the parameter with ``nil`` value (i.e. something like ``status=NULL`` as the query string for the POST request), to somehow reset the status flag.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2407

You just pass `nil` as the value and Alamofire does all the magic. The problem is most likely somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Ctibor Šebák! I also tried to passing ``nil`` but it turns out to make the parameter value be ``"Optional(\"SOME_STATUS\")"``...